# Oracle where condition search in a multiline string

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-like

I am trying to select the records thier 'Text' field match the following form:

```
__<sql>__ xyz __</sql>__
```

where __ means anything, and xyz represents the own word that I'm searching for.

Notice: the field 'Text' is a multiline string.

Here is the query, but it doesn't return any records:

```
Select * from reports where regexp_like (text, '(.*)<sql>(.*)(^|\s)xyz(\s|$)(.*)</sql>(.*)', 'i');
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @mirzasa the query, that I postet doesn't work.
I have updated the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it return error (what is error message)? Does it return too many records? Or too few?

Comment: @mrzasa it doesn't return any rows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `'i'` as the third argument to REGEXP_LIKE, to make the search case-insensitive.

Change that to `'in'`.   The additional `n` is another option to REGEXP functions: it tells the regular expression engine to allow `.` to match `chr(10)` (newline). The default behavior, without this option, is for `.` to **not** match newline.

Answer (score 2):

For this setup the plain old `LIKE` works fine. You need not even care about the new line charactes.

```
 where column1 LIKE '%<sql>%xyz%</sql>%'
```

will do the job.

For a **case insensitive** search add `LOWER`

```
 where LOWER(column1) LIKE '%<sql>%xyz%</sql>%'
```

For a **context delimiter** search, e.g. whole word search simple replace all relevant *white space characters to blank*:

```
 where replace(replace(lower(column1),CHR(10),' '),CHR(9),' ') LIKE '%<sql>% xyz %</sql>%';
```

Here I'm replacing *new line* and *tab*, feel free to add other, e.g. CHR(13) if required.

*General rule is - if you may use `LIKE` prefer it to `REGEXP` as the performance of `LIKE` is much better.*

Simple demo:

```
create   table MYTABLE(column1 varchar2(1000))
;

insert into MYTABLE(column1) values('bla bla <sql> bla'||chr(10)||' xyz bla </sql> bla');
insert into MYTABLE(column1) values('bla bla <sql> bla'||chr(10)||' NO MACTH bla </sql> bla');
commit;

select * from MYTABLE;

COLUMN1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
-------------------
bla bla <sql> bla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 xyz bla </sql> bla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

bla bla <sql> bla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 NO MACTH bla </sql> bla

 select * from MYTABLE 
 where column1 LIKE '%<sql>%xyz%</sql>%';

 COLUMN1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
-------------------
bla bla <sql> bla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 xyz bla </sql> bla
```

Comment: In your solution you don't take the case-sensetivity and the whole word search into considaration.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji : using `lower()` will take care of it

Comment: @KaushikNayak lower doesn't solve the problem of whole word search.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - it will only take care of the case-insensitive search. If you read the OP's code, though, you will see there was a good reason to use a regular expression approach. The OP didn't explain EVERYTHING his query does, he only explained the part he needed help with; but if you inspect the regular expression, you will see there is more to it. ("Whole word search" in the OP's Comment just above yours.)

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji I addressed the whole word search, see update.